# Design: How to avoid calling destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

I got a `Window` class that is a wrapper to some C struct. 
The class has a static `vector<Window*> windows_` that is a list containing created windows. 
`Window` constructor does two things:

- `handle_ = SDL_CreateWindow( ... );` that basically allocates the C struct and store the pointer in a member variable `handle_`;
- pushes `this` in the list.

`Window` destructor does three things but only if `handle_` is not a `nullptr`:

- `SDL_DestroyWindow()` deallocates the C struct;
- removes `this` from the list.
- `handle_ = nullptr;`

Then, in my `main` I declare a `Window` as a local variable. 
When the window receives the `CLOSE` event, I call that window's destructor. 
Then, when the window goes out of scope, the window's destructor gets called again and I receive a segmentation error.

I know expicitly calling a destructor is delicate but I don't really know why. 
So the question is twofold:

Why is it crashing?

What design can I use to avoid calling the destructor?

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you could post a code sample.

Comment: The `this` you're pushing is going to be destroyed when it leaves scope on the caller-side of your creation code. Manually firing the destructor is a *bad* idea.

Comment: It looks like you’ve found out why calling an object’s destructor explicitly is rarely a good idea: it is likely to be called again when the object ends its regular lifecycle.

Comment: Don't use an automatic variable if you want to be able to destroy it before the end of the scope!

Comment: Are closing the window and destroying the window actually synonymous? If so the window shouldn't be closed it should be destroyed and the close will occur. If not the window shouldn't be destroyed when it is closed, rather it should just be closed and the destruction should happen at an appropriate time.

Comment: Why are you calling the destructor, if your object anyway goes out of scope just afterwards  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post some code so we can see exactly what is happening, but you're right that you **shouldn't manually call the destructor** because that will cause undefined behavior (see AliciaBytes' answer).  Instead, add a method to the class to close the window, and use the class to provide a safe interface to the SDL window functions.  Here is a sketch:

```
class Window {
private:
    SDL_Window *window_;

public:
    Window() : window_(nullptr) { }
    Window(const Window &) = delete;
    Window(Window &&w) : window_(w.window_) { w.window_ = nullptr; }
    Window(const char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 flags)
        : window(SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags))
    { }

    ~Window()
    {
        if (window_ != nullptr)
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window_);
    }

    Window &operator=(const Window &) = delete;
    Window &operator=(Window &&w)
    {
        if (window_) { SDL_DestroyWindow(window_); window_ = nullptr; }
        window_ = w.window_;
        w.window_ = nullptr;
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return window_ != nullptr;
    }

    void close()
    {
        if (window_ != nullptr) {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window_);
            window_ = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So basically the close method and the destructor should do the same thing. I was calling ~Window inside the close method but the destructor should be the one calling the close method.

Comment: Well, they both close the window, if it is open.  But the `close()` method sets the window pointer to null, so it is safe to call multiple times.  The destructor is not supposed to be called multiple times, so it doesn't bother setting the window pointer to null.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be calling the destructor to variables with automatic storage explicitly, this is undefined behavior:

Standard 12.4`[class.dtor]`/15

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer
>   exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an
>   object whose lifetime has ended (3.8). [ **Example: if the destructor
>   for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is
>   subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit
>   destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. —end example** ]

instead of looking for a **"hacky"** way of disabling the automatic destructor call or something else you should probably look for a better design.

Making a `DestroyWindow()` member function that takes care of the cleanup and sets a flag inside the class, but having the destructor check that flag and destroy the window (+ the other cleanup) if it wasn't done manually would already fix a lot.

---

To make it clear you probably want it like the `fstream` and other streams in the standard library. You can explicitly call close on them, but if you don't do it it gets done in the destructor for you as to not leak resources. But note that this **shouldn't be done through explicit destructor calls. (`fstream` for example got a `close` member function for explicitly closing it.)**

Answer (score 0):

Calling the destructor is delicate because it leaves an object in an undefined state. Any read from this object is undefined. In praticular, calling the destructor second time - which will always happen for local variables.

I think in your case you mixed the operations on the list with those on the window.

A constructor should only stabilize the invariant on the *current* object. Putting it inside a list should not be the responsibility of the constructor, in normal circumstances.

Don't call the destructor on `CLOSE`. Deallocate the struct, and put `nullptr` in `_handler`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to keep state as to whether your resource was cleaned up. Typically you set a handle to -1 or a pointer to nullptr:

```
class MyResourceContainer {
    MyResourceContainer(int someParameter) {
        open(someParameter);
    }

    ~MyResourceContainer() {
        close();
    }

    void open(int someParameter) {
        if(handle > -1) {
            // throw exception or close(), whatever you prefer
        } 

        // allocate resource using specified parameter
        handle = 42;
    }

    // can be called multiple times
    void close() {
        if(handle > -1) {
            // release resource
            handle = -1;
        }
    }

private:
    int handle = -1;
};
```